# SQL where statement and matching dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, inner-join, where-clause

Customer_profile table

```
userid   -   initialDepositSuccessDate
111111            2016-08-01
222222            2016-08-15
```

player_activity table

```
userid   -        Date       -    Deposit
111111            2016-08-01       $5.00 
111111            2016-08-02       $10.00 
111111            2016-08-03       $15.00
222222            2016-08-05       $0.00
222222            2016-08-08       $0.00
222222            2016-08-15       $20.00
```

my query

```
Select pa.userid, pa.deposit
from player_activity pa
INNER JOIN customer_profile cp
    on cp.userid = pa.userid
where pa.depositmade_amt <> 0
    AND cp.amountGamingPlayerBalancecurrent > 0
    AND cp.accountStatus = 'active'
    AND pa.date =  cp.initialDepositSuccessDate
```

Ideally, i want my query would return this result:

```
pa.userid  pa.Deposit
111111     $5.00 
222222     $20.00
```

but instead it returns this:

```
pa.userid  pa.Deposit
111111       $5.00 
222222       $0.00
```

Help?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question completely -- your sample data doesn't match your fields in your query.  With that said, it appears your query does return your expected results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e305/1

Comment: made some edits. hopefully it makes more sense to you

Comment: Your query should return your desired output. You must be either using a different query or having different contents in your tables. Maybe repeated rows with different `accountStatus`?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: And what are the columns' data types?  I'm specifically interested in the `deposit` column. Is it numeric, or is it a string?

Comment: mysql. deposit is a float.

Comment: Do the dates fields have time or are they just dates?

Comment: depositmade? What's that? I think you can do better.

Comment: @eddd83, any update?

Comment: @andrew long story short, i figured out the solution on my own. thanks though.

Comment: Why don't you share it with everybody? That's what StackOverflow is about. Someone may come across the same issue in the future and find your question.

Comment: alright. fair enough. i didn't think about it that way. basically I forgot that some of my other  where conditions `AND cp.amountGamingPlayerBalancecurrent > 0
    AND cp.accountStatus = 'active' ` would eliminate some results. hence why I saw a shorter results list than anticipated. major brain fart on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to compare only date part (not time)

Maybe you can use Convert function to convert to date type

```
Convert(date, pa.date)=Convert(date, cp.initialDepositSuccessDate)
```